# Discord.js V13 TypeError: (intermediate value).setName(...).setDescription(...).addAttachmentOption is not a function

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');

const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('test')
    .setDescription('test')
    .addAttachmentOption(option =>
        option.setName('img')
            .setDescription('the image')
    )
            

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken("token");

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands("id", "id"), { body: data })
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);
```

getting the TypeError: (intermediate value).setName(...).setDescription(...).addAttachmentOption is not a function error idk why

Comment: Which version of `discord.js` do you have?

Comment: What's your exact discord.js ```npm list discord.js``` and node ```node -v``` version?

Answer (score -1):

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { REST, Routes } = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json")

const commands = [];

commands.push(
    new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('test')
    .setDescription('test')
    .addAttachmentOption(option =>
        option.setName('img')
            .setDescription('the image')
    )
)


const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken("token");

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands("guild", "client"), { body: commands })
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);
```

This worked for me, not sure what @discordjs/rest is but it is not needed as the REST object is available to grab from discord.js directly, make sure to remove `const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest'); const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');` since they are not needed.